# How to list all included header files by a c file (preferably in Vim)

Tags: vim, include, preprocessor, header-files

Is there a way to see all the header files included by a c file.

Lets say a c file contians only one header file, but that header file
includes 10 header files, and those 10 include further more and so on...

I want to get a list of all header files that eventually get included

Answer (score 4):

But the real command for this is

```
:checkpath
```

It will list the missing headers. To see *all* headers (in a reference tree)

```
:checkpath!
```

You will want to learn about the meaning of the `'include'`, `'isfname'` and `'path'` settings in the context of this include checking. Obviously, the defaults will work ok for C/C++ sources. Many filetype plugins will come with appropriate definitions to work with other types of files.

Answer (score 3):

A common technique is to use cpp:

```
$ cpp -M file.c
```

Comment: But that doesn't work when include files are present in some include/ directory(as specified in Makefile)

Comment: Add a -I option to cpp, or set CPATH in the environment in which cpp is run, and specify the directory there.  eg cpp -I/include1 -I/include2 -M file.c or CPATH=/include1:/include2 cpp -M file.c

Answer (score 0):

You can use -E -H with CC. Similar options should exist for gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I found that a useful CL switch is this switch:

```
/ShowIncludes
```

It causes CL to output to *stdout* a somewhat indented listing like the one below. It can give you the hierarchy from which header file they are included:

```
Note: including file: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\windows.h
Note: including file:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\sdkddkver.h
Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\excpt.h
Note: including file:   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\sal.h
Note: including file:     c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\codeanalysis\sourceannotations.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\vadefs.h
Note: including file:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\stdarg.h
Note: including file:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\windef.h
Note: including file:   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\winnt.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\ctype.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\specstrings.h
Note: including file:     c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1\include\sal_supp.h
Note: including file:     c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1\include\specstrings_supp.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\specstrings_strict.h
Note: including file:      C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\specstrings_undef.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\driverspecs.h
Note: including file:      c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.1\include\sdv_driverspecs.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\kernelspecs.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\basetsd.h
Note: including file:    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\INCLUDE\guiddef.h
Note: including file:     C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\string.h
Note: including file:      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h
... and the list continues
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.